# PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php, session

I read the answers here [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) but this not fix my error.

i don't understand, session_start() is the first thing i call in my files and I am using the UTF-8 without BOM encoding. But i still get this php warning.

Error :

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/feyzprod/public_html/nearby/register.php:1) in /home/feyzprod/public_html/nearby/register.php on line 1
```

My file encoding is

```
Encoding is UTF-8 without BOM
```

Code :

```
<?php session_start();
    require_once('bdservice.php');
    require_once('script.php');

    $bd = new BDService();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>NearBy Me : Courtier immobiliers</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ico.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formoid.net/forms/30/17477/formoid-default-skyblue.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://formoid.net/lib/iframe.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formoid.net/lib/form.css" type="text/css" />

<script>

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class='bar'>
        <div class='header'>
            <div id='left'></div>

            <div id='right'>
                <div style='margin-top:35px;'>
                <span><a href='#'>Français</a> | <a href='#'>Anglais</a></span><br/><br/>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['authentification']))
                    {
                        echo "<a href='profil.php'><button class=\"large green button\">Profil</button></a>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<a href='connexion.php'><button class=\"large green button\">Login</button></a>";
                    }
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style='clear:both;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='inscription'>
        <img src='images/inscription.png' alt='inscription' title='inscription' /><br/><br/>
            <?php
                if(!isset($_POST['Valider']))
                {
```

Comment: you start a session only one time, in one file! Did you don't have another `session_start()` on bdservice.php or script.php?

Comment: bdservice.php and script.php don't have session_start()

Comment: try use `ob_start();` before of the `session_start();`

Comment: I still get the same warning

Comment: check in your php.ini if you have `session.auto_start = 1`, if yes change to `session.auto_start = 0`.

Comment: I think I found the problem, the encoding in notepad++ is UTF-8 without BOM but when I upload my file the encoding become only UTF-8. I don't know why ...

Comment: I don't think this has to do with the BOM thing

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a space or other whitespace character at the beginning of `/home/feyzprod/public_html/nearby/register.php`, indicated in your error that it is on line 1.

The space will echo to the output which means that you can no longer write to the headers, which is where PHP wants to set the session information via a cookie.

Comment: the beginning of /home/feyzprod/public_html/nearby/register.php is the code show in my original post and my file using utf-8 without BOM, there should be no whitespace at the beginning of the file

Comment: @seb It really sounds like there is some hidden newline/whitespace character at the beginning of your file...